# iReport 5.6.0 not working

Tags: ireport

I installed iReport from the offical site.
When I lunch it I see:
[image]

after few seconds the view is gone and nothing happens. No error... nothing.

I tried both exe (install) version and the zip version.

anyone knows what might be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to:

   ```
       "iReport-5.6.0/etc/ireport.conf"
   ```
2. You will see:

   ## jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
3. Now just remove '#' i.e. uncomment it.It will look like

   ```
        jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
   ```
4. set your jdk home path in double coat.

   ```
        jdkhome="your jdk path to be here"
   ```
5. Enjoy the iReport-5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

You must be using JRE8 to run iReport. Install JRE7 and specify its path in the *etc/ireport.conf* file as `jdkhome` (this property is commented out by default).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply download the ireport plugin from netbeans website and install the plugin to your netbeans ide instead of running a different app for the design, the plugin also has every feature the designer has and this doesnt require you installing jdk 6 or 7. As others have said, installing jdk 7 and configuring the ireport conf file home to your jdk 7 file path e.g jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79"